# Specific way to allow Wordpress users to view their current password? And edit it?

Tags: plugins, users, security, password, s2member

I know the built in user manager doesn't allow a user to see what her current pass is, just recover / reset it via email or write in a new one in the admin but I am looking for a plugin or other method to circumvent this and allows for the creation of a user profile page that permits a user to see her current password in a field and update it form there, if they wish.

I realize standard Wordpress won't allow this so I am open to a plugin like s2member -- or any other -- but not sure if any of them do this.

I use Amember on one site and it integrates with WordPress via a plugin and you may edit and view passwords in Amember in the way I mentioned but I can't host Amember on a host like WPENGINE with additional security stringency.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Viewing passwords is not possible, because they are not stored anywhere. WordPress stores just the [hash of the password](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Password_verification), not the password itself. When a user sends her password to authenticate herself, WordPress creates a hash of the sent password and compares *that* to the stored hash.

You should not try to store the passwords as plain text anywhere. That would be a *huge* security problem.

Comment: Right. Thanks Toscho. I was aware that passwords were stored in that way. It's just that in some cases when your blog isn't protecting highly sensitive info, allow users to see their actual password in a user profile menu and change it easily would make things easier.